# Firebase function: manipulate admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to automatically create an expiration timestamp for new items that are added to the Firebase database. So I wrote the following function:

```
exports.onCreateNewItem = functions.database.ref('/items/{item_id}').onCreate(event => {
    var mergedUpdate = {};
    mergedUpdate['expiration'] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP + 2678400000;
    return event.data.adminRef.update(mergedUpdate);
})
```

However, it doesn't work. The value in `/items/{item_id}/expiration` is `"[object Object]2678400000"` while I expected it to be the timestamp of 31 days from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your Cloud Function code runs on a Google server, you have access to the server time via [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).  You don't need to use `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

```
exports.onCreateNewItem = functions.database.ref('/items/{item_id}').onCreate(event => {
    var mergedUpdate = {};
    mergedUpdate['expiration'] = Date.now() + 2678400000;
    return event.data.adminRef.update(mergedUpdate);
})
```

Comment: While this is indeed correct, there are a few nuances. For example: the values of `Date.how()` and `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` are not guaranteed (and unlikely) to be the same. This means that you can't use `Date.now()` and successfully compare it to `now` in security rules for example. So: while your approach is probably fine for many cases, it's not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: As long as the difference is within the minutes-range, I'm ok. Is this not the case?

Comment: The difference in times that Frank identifies in his comment will never be more than a second.